# printf() formatting for hexadecimal

Tags: c, printf, hex

Why, when printing a number in hexadecimal as an 8 digit number with leading zeros, does `%#08X` *not* display the same result as `0x%08X`?

When I try to use the former, the `08` formatting flag is removed, and it doesn't work with just `8`.

Comment: Do you mean `0x%.8X` ? That *will* lead-fill with zeros. (the `0x` is just a preamble, but your likely already aware of that).

Answer (score 403):

The `#` part gives you a `0x` in the output string. The `0` and the `x` count against your "8" characters listed in the `08` part. You need to ask for 10 characters if you want it to be the same.

```
int i = 7;

printf("%#010x\n", i);  // gives 0x00000007
printf("0x%08x\n", i);  // gives 0x00000007
printf("%#08x\n", i);   // gives 0x000007
```

Also changing the case of `x`, affects the casing of the outputted characters.

```
printf("%04x", 4779); // gives 12ab
printf("%04X", 4779); // gives 12AB
```

Comment: The top line outputs 14F0x00000007 for me. The second and third work as written.

Comment: @quantumpotato - That's... odd. The first and third lines are identical with the exception of the number of 0's they should produce. What was your compiler/system/line of code that produced this? Did you have any lines proceeding the one that printed `14F`?

Comment: Note that if `i = 0;`, the versions using `%#` will not include the `0x` prefix.

Comment: but how about the hex: 0x43A66C31C68491C0
I have tried the following:
__int64 int64 = 0x43A66C31C68491C0;
printf_s("%#15X %d",int64,int64);
But the output is      0XC68491C0, not 0x43A66C31C68491C0

Comment: About the hex 0x43A66C31C68491C0 above, I have solve it, the solution is 0x%I64X , not %#15X

Comment: @123iamking - The one thing I could caution is that `printf_s` is a MSDN function where as this answer is specifically calling out `printf`... I am not really sure if all the same flags/format options are supported, but I would be leery of making any assumption on that point.

Comment: Is there any way to pad `0` at the end?

Answer (score 68):

The "0x" counts towards the eight character count. You need `"%#010x"`.

Note that `#` does *not* append the 0x to 0 - the result will be `0000000000` - so you probably actually should just use `"0x%08x"` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `#` does not prepend "0x" to "0"!

Answer (score 43):

The `%#08X` conversion must precede the value with `0X`; that is required by the standard.  There's no evidence in the standard that the `#` should alter the behaviour of the `08` part of the specification except that the `0X` prefix is counted as part of the length (so you might want/need to use `%#010X`.  If, like me, you like your hex presented as `0x1234CDEF`, then you have to use `0x%08X` to achieve the desired result.  You could use `%#.8X` and that should also insert the leading zeroes.

Try variations on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    printf("0x%.8X = %#08X = %#.8X = %#010x\n", j, j, j, j);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        j = (j << 4) | (i + 6);
        printf("0x%.8X = %#08X = %#.8X = %#010x\n", j, j, j, j);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

On an [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 5 machine, and also on [Mac OS X v10.7.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion), the output was:

```
0x00000000 = 00000000 = 00000000 = 0000000000
0x00000006 = 0X000006 = 0X00000006 = 0x00000006
0x00000067 = 0X000067 = 0X00000067 = 0x00000067
0x00000678 = 0X000678 = 0X00000678 = 0x00000678
0x00006789 = 0X006789 = 0X00006789 = 0x00006789
0x0006789A = 0X06789A = 0X0006789A = 0x0006789a
0x006789AB = 0X6789AB = 0X006789AB = 0x006789ab
0x06789ABC = 0X6789ABC = 0X06789ABC = 0x06789abc
0x6789ABCD = 0X6789ABCD = 0X6789ABCD = 0x6789abcd
```

I'm a little surprised at the treatment of 0; I'm not clear why the `0X` prefix is omitted, but with two separate systems doing it, it must be standard.  It confirms my prejudices against the `#` option.

---

The treatment of zero is according to the standard.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 [§7.21.6.1 **The `fprintf` function**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p6)

> ¶6 The flag characters and their meanings are:
> ...
> `#` The result is converted to an "alternative form". ... For `x` (or `X`)
> conversion, a ***nonzero*** result has `0x` (or `0X`) prefixed to it. ...

(Emphasis added.)

---

Note that using `%#X` will use upper-case letters for the hex digits and `0X` as the prefix; using `%#x` will use lower-case letters for the hex digits and `0x` as the prefix.  If you prefer `0x` as the prefix and upper-case letters, you have to code the `0x` separately: `0x%X`.  Other format modifiers can be added as needed, of course.

For printing addresses, use the `<inttypes.h>` header and the `uintptr_t` type and the `PRIXPTR` format macro:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *address = &address;  // &address has type void ** but it converts to void *
    printf("Address 0x%.12" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)address);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Address 0x7FFEE5B29428
```

Choose your poison on the length — I find that a precision of 12 works well for addresses on a Mac running macOS.  Combined with the `.` to specify the minimum precision (digits), it formats addresses reliably.  If you set the precision to 16, the extra 4 digits are always 0 in my experience on the Mac, but there's certainly a case to be made for using 16 instead of 12 in portable 64-bit code (but you'd use 8 for 32-bit code).

Answer (score 13):

`#` causes `0x` (or `0X` for `%#X`) to be prepended to the output unless the value is `0`, so you should not use `#` if you want `0x` to always appear in the output.

You can use the width field combined with the `0` flag to produce leading zeroes: `%08x` pads the number with leading zeroes to a width of `8`. If you want consistent output for all 32-bit values, use `"0x08x"`.

You could also use the precision field: `%.8x` pads the number with leading zeroes to a total of `8` digits. Hence you can also use `"0x%.8x"` for your purpose.

These conversion specifications would differ if a prefix is generated as part of the conversion, such as `0x` for `#` or `-` for negative numbers in signed conversions, whose length is counted for the width but not for the precision specifier. Furthermore, the precision field can be combined with the width field:

```
printf("|%10x|", 256)      // outputs |       100|
printf("|%010x|", 256)     // outputs |0000000100|
printf("|%#010x|", 256)    // outputs |0x00000100|

printf("|%10.8x|", 256)    // outputs |  00000100|
printf("|%#10.8x|", 256)   // outputs |0x00000100|
printf("|0x%.8x|", 256)    // outputs |0x00000100|

printf("|%10x|", 0)        // outputs |         0|
printf("|%010x|", 0)       // outputs |0000000000|
printf("|%#010x|", 0)      // outputs |0000000000|

printf("|%10.8x|", 0)      // outputs |  00000000|
printf("|%#10.8x|", 0)     // outputs |  00000000|
printf("|0x%.8x|", 0)      // outputs |0x00000000|
```

I would recommend using the last one: `"0x%.8x"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use "%p" in order to display 8 bit hexadecimal numbers.

```
int main (void)
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    a = 15;
    b = a << 28;
    printf("%p", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xf0000000
```

Comment: What environment defines `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`?

Comment: Starting off with `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdint.h>` may be sufficient.

Comment: With that content, on Linux, `gcc -x c  Hexprint_p.c` results in `warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint32_t’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]`.

Comment: The output of `%p` is implementation dependent and passing an `int32_t` for `%p` has undefined behavior. Definitely not a good solution.

Comment: In my implementation, works perfectly! However the result is trunk at left for zeros (```printf("Sl_1: %p\n", 0x0123)``` => ```Sl_1: 0x123```)