# Unit-Test : Compare Expected Result with hexadezimal

Tags: c, unit-testing, hex, decimal

I want to compare a hexadecimal with a hexadecimal and show if its the same. For Example:

```
decimal = 255 
ExpResult = FF 
Hex[x] = FF --> true
```

Comment: In `if (ExpResult != hexa[x])` where `x` is now `0` you have not written anything to `hexa[0]`.

Comment: `char ExpResult` --> `unsigned char ExpResult`

Comment: C does not have hexadecimal variables. See [ask]. What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: `if (ExpResult != decimal)`......It's a kjind of magic.....? ;)

Comment: I could use a function which proves if the result is a hexadecimal too.
For example a string or something else, but i dont know how I can transfer the "hex[x]" variable out of the converter.
I cant tranfer FF as an identifer too

Comment: The value in `ExpResult` is not hex, is decimal too, as for `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a program that compares 2 arguments of your program and outputs if they are matching or not...
Hope it will help ;)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char *malloc_hexa(unsigned int num)
{
  int       len = 0;

  if (num == 0)
    len = 1;
  while (num > 0)
    {
      num /= 16;
      len++;
    }
  return (malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1)));
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char      *tmp = NULL;
  unsigned int  num = 0;

  if (ac != 3)
    {
      printf("Use: ./test [number] [Hexa]\n");
      return (1);
    }
  num = (unsigned int)atoi(av[1]);
  if (!(tmp = malloc_hexa(num)))
    return (1);
  if (sprintf(tmp, "%X", num) <= 0)
    return (1);
  if (!strcmp(tmp, av[2]))
    printf("match: %s / %s\n", tmp, av[2]);
  else
    printf("no match: %s / %s\n", tmp, av[2]);
  free(tmp);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Side note: if sprintf fails you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: yep, I forgot that. You could just add a free() before the return in the if condition for sprintf...

Answer (score 0):

Any reason that you have declared `ExpResult` argument as `char`? and also code is a bit unreadable ( use some tabs ).

I will write some pesu-code :

```
First get the number input from user.
Calculate the hexadecimal value with an algorithm.
Print it. // printing hexadecimal is another story itself
get that hex value from user.
Check it with the expected value.
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733761/printf-formatting-for-hex) for printing (formatted) hexadecimal values.

Comment: I did that .. I only copy the problematic part of my code .. because its very long and unclear

Comment: @jackobhusein the point is that you should write your code clear and wrap them in functions so the next time you want to edit your code understand What is What...

Comment: i dont think its possible to support 255+ for using only c.

Comment: if you use `int` you can ( even `double` ) or `LARGE_INTEGER` on WinApi

Comment: Edited my code :
This is my problem
"Check it with the expected value."