# Transferring a string of characters in quotes to an array of ascii2 bytes in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

How do I easily convert a string of characters in quotes to an array of ascii2 values?

For example:

```
char ST1[5] = "12345";
```

to

```
char DST1[5] = { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 }; //string of bytes
```

Comment: The two are equivalent, and don't need any conversion. Just use `memcpy`, you can't use `strcpy` because they are not strings (no NUL terminator).

Comment: What is "ascii2"?

Answer (score 0):

**Practically nothing.**

First, remember that string literals such as `"12345"` have an extra "null" byte at the end.  So instead of treating this array initialization of `"12345"` to an array of 5 elements, it's really an array of 6 elements, so this initialization statement is more appropriate:

`char ST1[6] = "12345";`

Or just simply:

`char ST1[] = "12345";`  // where the size of "6" is auto inferred.

Which is equivalent to:

`char DST1[] = {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x00};`

And once you have an array of 6 elements, you can pass it around as if it had only 5:

So if you have some code that expects to operate on an array of 5 chars:

```
 void foo(char DST1[])
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     { 
         process(DST1[i]);
     }
 }
```

You can invoke it as follows:

```
char ST1[]="12345";
foo(ST1);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I meant ASCII didn't need the extra  2... I need to send the actual bytes to a UART so I suppose I could use                                                 sprintf(DST1[i]"%d\n",(int)ST1[i]); in the loop.

Comment: `memcpy(DST, ST1, count*sizeof(*DST));`

Comment: The `sprintf` loop you propose will literally copy `"4950515253"` into your buffer.

Comment: But why copy ST1 into DST1 when you can just pass ST1 into the UART API.

Comment: Actually as Selbie said, all I needed to do was                                    for(i=5;i>0;i--)DST1[i]=ST1[i]; and that worked fine.

Comment: Just saw your post- The UART subroutine outputs a buffer called Data_Out[], so i need to put the string of characters in that buffer. So actually what I did was..                                            
 for(i=5;i>0;i--)Data_Out[i]=ST1[i]; and that worked, Are you saying there is an easier way to put the string into the buffer?

Comment: Oh I see.  Then the `memcpy` statement in my comment above will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

One for all, one answer is casting.
Easy way to do it:

```
int main () {
    int i;
    char ST1[5]="12345";
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d\n",(int)ST1[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Just like I printed, you can store it, calculate using it or anything possible. And as I see, you want those number in hexadecimals. For that, just change the `printf`'s placeholder with help from here - [printf() formatting for hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733761/printf-formatting-for-hex#14733875)

Comment: You don't need the cast: `char` is promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: I'm a noob as well and that's why I said "one answer". My bad. Anyway, it's correct and it's all that matters to me.

Comment: Most of the time you'd want to cast to unsigned char and print with %hhu

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the definitions of `ST1` and `DST1` is the silent assumption that the target character set is ASCII, at least for the digits.

Here is another alternative:

```
char CST1[5] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

Note however that none of these `char` arrays are proper C strings because they all lack a null terminator. If you with to define an array that is a C string, you should use this syntax:

```
char SST1[] = "12345";
```

Notice the missing length between the `[]`: the compiler will determine the length of the array from the initializer and add a null terminator, hence a length a `6`.

C strings can be copies with `strcpy`, `char` arrays that do not have a null terminator should be copied with `memcpy` or `memmove`.