# How do you use printf to format pointer values as 0x0000...?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

When I use `printf` to print pointer values, they display in the format:
`000000000066FE14`. I would like them to display in the `0x` format, such as: `0x66FE14`.

This is the simple test program I wrote to print pointer values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 4;
    int *xAddress = &x;

    printf("Address of x: %p\n", xAddress);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
Address of x: 000000000066FE14
```

Comment: Do you mean "How do I trim off the leading 0 values in a pointer represented as a hex string?" Tip: Use `sprintf` and trim away!

Comment: I guess so. As printf uses formatting I was wondering if there was a certain format specifier that did it, hence the wording.

Comment: I think it's going to put leading 0 values in there for you, they're not optional like on `%d` and such. Maybe `sprintf`, then use that buffer offset to the first non-zero value.

Comment: Strictly, you should coerce `xAddress` into a `void *` before using it with `printf()` and `%p`.  In this context, you could simply use `void *xAddress = &x;` with no explicit cast needed.  In many contexts, you'd need to use `(void *)xAddress` in the argument list to `printf()`.

Comment: Note that some systems would print the hex address with a `0x` or `0X` prefix — the `%p` conversion specification is allowed to do that, but it is also allowed to omit them (as on your system).  If you want portable behaviour, you'll probably convert to `uintptr_t` and then format with that and `PRIXPTR` or `PRIxPTR`, etc.  Note that in theory, there might not be a type `uintptr_t` (an unsigned integer type that can hold any valid pointer to an object — pointers to functions have separate rules). In practice, I've not heard of a system where it is unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When run in [this editor,](https://repl.it/repls/CrimsonSpiffyViruses) it looks like the program *is* printing your pointer in hex format. `%p` is also the convention for printing pointers. That being said, if you want to format your printing to be in the 0x format, you'd likely be interested in [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14733761/7431860) which gives some tips on how to print in hex format.

Maybe cast the pointer's address to a `(void *)` first? Could be causing implementation-specific issues if your pointer type is `(int *)`

`printf("Address of x: %p\n", (void *)xAddress);`

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `uintptr_t` type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int x = 4;
    int *xAddress = &x;

    printf("Address of x: 0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) xAddress);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The C standard does not define the format used by the `%p` specifier; it is left to each implementation to define. To control the formatting of an address, you can convert it to the `uintptr_t` type and print that. To do this, include the `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdint.h>` headers, in addition to the `<stdio.h>` header. Then convert the pointer to `uintptr_t` with a cast and use the `PRIxPTR` or `PRIXPTR` macros (for lowercase or uppercase, respectively).

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("0X%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t) &a);
}
```

This will print the pointer using a hexadecimal format. Whether that hexadecimal value corresponds to a hardware memory address is not guaranteed by the C standard, although the conversion from a pointer to an integer is intended to be unsurprising to a person familiar with the architecture.

Comment: Suggest `"0x%" PRIXPTR` to print `0x0` when the pointer is a zero, else only `0` is printed with `"%#" PRIXPTR`

Comment: @chux: If `(uintptr_t) &a` is zero, you have got bigger problems than whether “0X” is printed with it. :-) But updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Address of x: 0x%x\n", xAddress);
```

Comment: The behavior of using `%x` with a pointer is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 7.21.6.1 9: “… If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil It would be possible after converting it to uintptr_t, however

Comment: @Ctx but the conversion itself is implementation defined, so there is no saying what would be printed.

Answer (score 0):

To `printf` as hex output, you have to add the `0x` prefix yourself:

`printf("0x%08x\n", xAddress);`

This will print `xAddress`, prefixed with `0x`, and then filled with leading `0` and the address for 8 digits. If you know you want exactly 6 digits, and you don't want the leading `0`, you can use `0x%6x`.

Comment: The behavior of using `%x` with a pointer is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 7.21.6.1 9: “… If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”

Answer (score 0):

printf("0x%016llx", (void* __ptr64)xAddress);   //visualstudio