# How to convert binary array into a hexadecimal in C

Tags: c, hex, byte

So currently I have an array of binary digits, say {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} and I'm trying to figure out how I can convert this array into a hexadecimal digit of type 'uint8_t' in C (in this example, I would want it to be 0xf0) except I'm struggling to figure out how to do so. So far I've been able to convert the digit to hexadecimal string except I want it to be an unsigned integer type. Could anyone please provide me some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with convert to hex? once you [convert the binary format string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343099/convert-binary-format-string-to-int-in-c) you can print this `int` (or `uint8_t` in your case) with `"%x"` which is the [format specifier for hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733761/printf-formatting-for-hex)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t ConvertToDec(uint16_t* bits, uint16_t size)
{
    uint16_t result = 0;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        result |= bits[i];
        if(i != size-1)
            result <<= 1;
    }

    return result;

}

int main()
{
    uint16_t bits[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    uint16_t len = (sizeof(bits) / sizeof(bits[0])); // get array size
    uint16_t result = ConvertToDec(bits, len);
    char hex[20];
    sprintf(hex, "0x%02X", result);
    printf("%s", hex);

    return 0;
}
```

ConvertToDec converts the array into 8 bit number, and using sprintf saves the output as hex into the hex buffer.
Edit : I have modified the code a little bit making it more readable and also to work with 16 bit numbers as well.

Best regards

Comment: Hello thank you for this! I have a few questions thought. First, why is it in the convert_to_dec function you have i < size - 1, as wouldn't this skip the last digit? Also, would this method happen to work for if the bit array was say, size = 4 instead?

Comment: @oliviah Hello first the -1 in the loop was because on the last cycle the 8th digit was lost, yes it can work with the size of 4 as well. I have modified the code a bit making it more readable and adding to work with 16 bit numbers as well. Kind regards!